# Python code complexity as Sublime Text 3 Linter

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, code-complexity

I like the python package [radon](https://pypi.org/project/radon/) and use it fairly often to help find/reduce complex code.

I'm normally developing in Sublime Text, and running radon beside in console, but would **really like** to have radon (or something similar) in sublime that will flag my function w/ a complexity that gives me any ranking less than "A"..kinda like pylint does when my code is junk.

I looked around for a SublimeLinter plugin that would check code complexity as you are typing out function etc. Has anyone seen a SublimeLinter plugin like that?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) (the Sublime plug-in, not the Python distribution) has an option for McCabe complexity calculation. There are also a bunch of [`SublimeLinter` Python plugins](https://packagecontrol.io/search/sublimelinter%20py), including one for `pylint` if that's what you want - your question is rather unclear in that regard. I'll leave it up to you to research each one and see if it offers complexity calculations.

Comment: However, questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. You *may* be able to get help on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange, but *please* read through their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) **first** to ensure your question is on topic there.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks, yes, I'm using pylint and other linters in there, but specifically am looking for one to show complexity. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up making one :) https://github.com/christopherpickering/SublimeLinter-contrib-radon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a plugin for SublimeLinter.
https://github.com/christopherpickering/SublimeLinter-contrib-radon